# jQuery UI overlay without dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, overlay, jquery-ui-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery UI: How to use ui-widget-overlay by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782944/jquery-ui-how-to-use-ui-widget-overlay-by-itself)

I want to avoid the user to change the screen during ajax calls. So I was thinking to use jQuery UI overlay (the overlay of the modal dialogs) but without any dialog. I couldn't find any way to do this.

**Is there any way to show a modal without a dialog?**

Comment: What do you mean "without a dialog"? You mean without the dialog header?

Comment: No, without anything. Only the overlay.

Comment: Here's a similar question with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782944/jquery-ui-how-to-use-ui-widget-overlay-by-itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942956/310276) of another SO question.

[Here there is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/b23pd/1/).

And the code:

```
$("body").append($.ui.dialog.overlay.create())
```

Comment: nice trick, would be great to have something as simple as this but to be ale to overlay just one div.

Comment: doesn't work with jquery >= 1.10

Answer (score 2):

The dialog with the modal option set to true adds the following div, where width and height represent the viewable area in the browser window:

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 607px; height: 350px; z-index: 1001;"></div>
```

You could try something similar on your page. See http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal and then view source on the demo iframe for the complete source.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, but I don't want to calculate the width and height myself because of cross-browsing issues.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js

Their code shows that they call `_createOverlay()` and `_destroyOverlay()` on the widget.  You could try creating a dialog and init it with `autoOpen:false` and then invoke those methods manually.

Comment: what would the code look like to call those methods.

Something like this: $("#myDialg").dialog._createOverlay() ?
Not sure how to invoke those properly...

Comment: Broken link.  Please add code here instead of linking.