# How to make jQuery UI dialog occupy full window and dynamically adjust to window size change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

At the moment, I can set `width` attribute to `auto` to take the full width of the window, and it dynamically adjust itself if the window size is being changed (e.g. re-sizing the browser windows or displaying it on a different screen size). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NnsN2/

However, I can't get the `height` to work the same. It will always be the minimum height that will fit the content, even though I've tried setting it to `auto`.

The usual approach of getting the window height first (`$(window).height()`) and use that for `height` doesn't work here, because it will be static and will not dynamically adapt to change of window size.

How can I make the height always take the full height of the window as well as be able to adapt itself to window size change?

Comment: so you want the dialog to cover the whole window?

Comment: @Alnitak, yes, covers the whole window and automatically resizes itself when window size changes.

Comment: it seems to me then that a jQuery UI dialog is probably not the right control for the job...

Comment: @Alnitak, so what would be the right tool for the job?

Comment: that depends on what particular features of the jQuery dialog you need.  In the first instance I'd start with a high zIndex 100% width/height "overlay" div, and build up from there.  This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993471/jquery-ui-overlay-without-dialog

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try to get the element's `#id` or `.class` at runtime and then make the width/Height according to the window width and height:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
   $('.ui-dialog').css({
        'width': $(window).width(),
        'height': $(window).height(),
        'left': '0px',
        'top':'0px'
   });
}).resize(); //<---- resizes on page ready
```

[**checkout in fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NnsN2/1/)

Comment: this works. If the page is greater than the screen you can use `$(document).height` to get the content's full height

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I was able to "solve" this problem for jQuery UI Ver 1.8.17:

**After** the dialogue has been opened, and assuming that you have captured its id, use the following:

```
$("#DlgID").parent().css('height', $(window).height());
```

The actual height is dictated by the parent of your `<div>` containing the dialogue content, hence the reference.  You can also use this method to control other properties of the parent.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery plugin](https://github.com/meshesha/jqueryui.dialog.fullmode/blob/master/README.md) :

```
$("#demo").dialog({
   width: 500,
   height: 300,
   dialogClass: "dialog-full-mode" /*must to add this class name*/
 });
 //initiate the plugin
 $(document).dialogfullmode();
```

Comment: edit a bit your answer and insert the brackets into code brackets.