# jQuery preventDefault() even after .ajax()

Tags: jquery

When PHP script is pulled into my page using

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/assets/inc/user-stream-list.php",
    success: function (data) {
        $(".user-stream-list").html(data);
    }
});
```

It produces `<a>` and I currently use

```
$('.col-l .feed a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

To stop the links being able to be clicked but after I run the `.ajax()` script the links become clickable.

Is there a way to prevent the links being clickable after the ajax has run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate the `click` event to an element higher up the DOM that exists before the AJAX call is made.

For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.col-l .feed a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note how the `.on()` method with three arguments delegates the event to the `document` element, instead of binding it directly to the yet non-existing `a` elements. Naturally, `document` is as high as you can go up the DOM tree. But closer parents can be used as long as you know they exist beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Since the HTML is loaded in via AJAX, if you want to bind events to it, you need to bind them to the parent, using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and set a filter on it.

```
$(".user-stream-list").on('click', '.col-l .feed a', function() {
 ...
});
```

*EDIT: `live` is deprecated. use `on` instead.*

Comment: the click event still happens

Answer (score -1):

Use an overlay div with loading icon, to prevent clicks events from any element...

there is an example here: 
[jQuery: How can i create a simple overlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718951/jquery-how-can-i-create-a-simple-overlay)

check another example:
[How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation)

Comment: OP does not mean the links are active *during* the AJAX request, but rather *after*.